# iOS - How to draw a circle with a number/character in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I would like to create a UIView which would show a colored circle with a number or character in it. I have seen examples to create a circle, but how would I accomplish this?

I would want to place multiple of these views on the screen and connect them with lines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the number is just inside the circle, or the number actually sits on the arc? If you're in drawRect, you could use NSString's drawAtPoint:withFont: combined with CGContextRotateCTM to draw at the right angle.

Comment: something like this http://www.gotyourphoto.com/temp/circle.png

Comment: The number will be inside the circle, mostly at the center of the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know how to draw a circle, then you've got half of it solved :)  Let's say the circle is drawn in a `UIView` called `circleView`.

Now you want to create a `UILabel` to draw the letter in.

```
UILabel* circleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[circleLabel setText:@"letter goes here"];
```

And now you want to put the label on top of the `circleView`, so you add it as a subview:

```
[circleView addSubview:circleLabel];
```

At this point, depending on the size of `circleView` and the font size of `circleLabel`, the label may or may not be in the center of the circle.  Use the `setFrame` function on the `circleLabel` to adjust its position within the `circleView`.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Swift, iOS8
var letterLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
letterLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 50
letterLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
letterLabel.layer.borderWidth = 10
letterLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
letterLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Hoefler Text", size:75.0)
letterLabel.text = "A"
```

[image]